# Where is that Access macro called?

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have to update an old big Access app, which contains quite a few macros.  **I would like to identify if a macro is used, and from where it is called.**
I could not find a solution. I have MZ Tools and CSD Tools installed, but these do not seem to be of help. I have also tried to use the built in documentor to print the form properties to a PDF, but that does not include control properties and events, so no use either.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the built in dependency option. This means you will have to enable the track name autocorrect. However, FEW realize that you can turn on the tracking, but not have to turn on the autocorrect.

The result is a beautiful tree-view of dependencies of the given object. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Note that you can drill down and "surf" the application this way. And BOTH objects that depend on the selected, or the reverse – what objects do selected depend on.

And NOTE how clicking on any object will open it in design view. A remakrable feature that I wish other developerment systems had.

Note that if you not turn on auto correct tracking, then the first time this can take a significant amount of time and processing as all objects and their inverse of referencing takes place. However, once the index is built for this amazing feature, then response times and use of this feature should be near instant.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion. I knew the feature but I did not think about it for macros (I normally never use macros). On the other hand I have seen some very serious Access sources discourage the use of that feature, which sems to create bugs. Do you have any opinion about that ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this link](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t1860151.html), I finally wrote my own quick tool for this problem:

```
Sub listControlEvents()
'by Patrick Honorez - www.idevlop.com --- 15-févr-2013
'Purpose   : list buttons calling macros + macro name

    Dim f As AccessObject, frm As Form, c As Control

    For Each f In CurrentProject.AllForms
        Debug.Print f.NAME
        DoCmd.OpenForm f.NAME, acDesign, , , , acHidden
        Set frm = Forms(f.NAME)
        For Each c In frm.Controls
            If c.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
                If c.Properties("OnCLick") <> "[Event Procedure]" Then
                    Debug.Print , c.NAME,
                    Debug.Print c.Properties("OnClick")
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        DoCmd.Close acForm, f.NAME, acSaveNo
    Next f
End Sub
```